# "Nearby Words" Scrollbar for Dictionary Interface

Tags: php, html, dictionary

I'd like to implement a feature very similar to the "nearby words" bar for an entry on www.dictionary.com. Here's what that looks like:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFISG.png)

My database has about 47,000 entries, so I don't think loading them in all at once is the way to go (but I could be wrong).

Does anyone have any ideas (or examples) of how I should go about implementing this?

I appreciate any help, and hope you all have a great holiday weekend!

**Edit:** Thus far, I have implemented a search bar with autocomplete that pulls up the correct information for a searched word. For example, searching for "X" would generate a page with the definition, part of speech, etc. of X. What I want to do is add a scrollbar of words that are alphabetically before and after X on this generated page.

Comment: You need 'autocomplete' search - http://daveismyname.com/demos/autocomplete/ -> http://www.daveismyname.com/tutorials/php-tutorials/autocomplete-with-php-mysql-and-jquery-ui/ However, you should limit results, and start to send requests only if 4 (for example) characters from search term exists in db record(s), to avoid too many results...

Comment: I've actually implemented autocomplete already. But I'd like the scollbar to show a number of words (say 5 or so) on each alphabetical side of the current word. This way, the user can maneuver to different pages of close words.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? I don't understand if your question is ui related or server-side related.

Comment: Let's say the user searches for the word "dog" and the dictionary page for "dog" is generated. On this page, I would like to include a scrollbar of clickable words, which include "doh", "doi", and about 20 words of "dog" directly after dog in the dictionary, and "dof", "doe", and the same number of words right before "dog" in the dictionary. I would like all of these words to be clickable, leading to their own dictionary pages.

Comment: The example image I've included in the original post (http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFISG.png) pretty much is precisely what I would like to emulate!

Comment: I think this is a definitely a UI issue. I can handle the server-side requests and queries fairly well. I'm just not sure how to handle the UI design (how to contain the list, what HTML features to use, etc.).

Comment: I've updated my answer, with a possible solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all , 47K entries might be small and might be big, depending on the record size and server (?) current load.
I suggest you implement an SQL Query (assuming you have an SQL db of course) that will check for relevant suggestions using `LIKE` for the specific column.
also for this purpose I suggest you only start searching the db after the user pressed 3 (or similar) letters, since if he pressed 1 for example, you might get a large overhead in your server.

**Edit:** (comments summary)

For Scrollbar with relevant words containing the previous 20 words and the next 20 words, **it is highly recommended to bring more than just 40 words in a single server call**.

This is since a single server call bringing 20 or 200 will take roughly the same amount of time since the **majority of time is generally spent on passing a request to the server**. requesting the server a smaller range, close to the range displayed will result in more server calls overall - and hence higher overhead and longer execution time.

**Caching** the results that are not displayed on the client side and implementing logic to use those while the user scrolls out of the scope (or close to it) will result in a smoother execution.

Comment: I'm using a MySQL database to store the data. What I'd like to to is essentially create a list of all 47K terms and place it in the scrollbar. Then, when the user search for a word, they are redirected to that page (I already have this functionality implemented) and on the left side of the page, they can see words that are alphabetically listed, with the current word at the center of the frame. In theory, they should be able to scroll through this frame and see ALL of the words (but that might be asking too much, so I might just limit it to all of the words that begin with the same letter).

Comment: Limiting to the same letter is a good thought, always think about the amount of data you give your user and how it affects your application. I don't see a benefit in giving a giant list for the user to scroll in. If you need further assistance regarding the design / db querying let me know.

Comment: just saw your edit - if I understood correctly , when I search for 'aab', you would like the scroll to show 'aaa' and 'aac' (and maybe 'aad' and so on..) ? if so, that can also be acomplished via SQL query, but you need you indexes arranged correctly for efficiency. let me know if that is the case.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'd like to do. I have the database indexed on the lemmas, should the querying should be fairly efficient.

Comment: Ok, let me slow down a bit. So right now, I'd like to have a list of 41 "links" on each words page, shown in some sort of scrollable frame. At any given time, the frame will only show 21 links, where each link is redirects the user to a new word page. I want to include the 20 words before and 20 words after the current page's word. The user should be able to scroll up and see the above 20 or down to the below 20. However, at any given scrolling the current word would still be in the 21 shown words.

Comment: Ok, regarding the scrollable frame I can't assist you, but I'm guessing there are quite a few code snippets for this type of thing. I can recommend in terms of design - bringing more than the relevant 20 above and below for optimization, since bringing 20 words or 200 words will take about the same amount of time in a single call, but bringing another word each time the user scrolls (or 2..5..10) will take more server calls and hence a lot more time. edit: the logic for displaying the right words are also UI related and it isn't that important how you do it in terms of execution time.

Comment: Thanks Ron. I went ahead and just used 200 like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you question is more related to frontend development and this is is why I think that you should consider javascript solutions to implement this feature.

You could use JQuery autocomplete plugin coupled with an html field.

You can find here an example: [JQuery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

and link a JSON output from a PHP script that will query the database.

You will limit the request after having at least 2/3 characters in your field and refresh it  a second after the last input in the text field.

You can find a good tutorial that fits your need here:

[JQuery Autocomplete tutorial with PHP/MySQL](http://www.jqueryautocomplete.com/jquery-autocomplete-php-mysql-json-example.html)

**Edit:**

A result of what you could achieve is here (Javascript code):

```
$(function() {
var words = [
  {
    value: "doe",
    label: "doe",
    desc: "additional description for doe",
  },
  {
    value: "doi",
    label: "doi",
    desc: "additional description for doi",
  },
  {
    value: "dog",
    label: "dog",
    desc: "additional description for dog",
  },
  {
    value: "dog catcher",
    label: "dog catcher",
    desc: "additional description for dog catcher",
  },  
  {
    value: "dog sitter",
    label: "dog sitter",
    desc: "additional description for dog sitter",
  }
];
$( "#word" ).autocomplete({
  minLength: 0,
  source: words,
  focus: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#word" ).val( ui.item.label );
    return false;
  },
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#word" ).val( ui.item.label );
    $( "#word-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
    $( "#word-description" ).html( ui.item.desc )

    return false;
  }
})
.data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
  return $( "<li>" )
    .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
    .appendTo( ul );
};
 });
```

[Working JSFiddle with custom JQuery Autocomplete](http://jsfiddle.net/FwczM/1/)

Comment: Thank you! I've ran this this idea as a basis, and now I have it working as I would like :)